# Android - Something Odd... Question

Tags: android

Something odd is going on, I think...

I have menu with sub-menu items.
One sub-menu gets GPS location, does some calc's and updates two display fields.  No problems.

The other sub-menu takes user input and does calc's **BUT**, it uses the same display stuff as the fist sub-menu but, won't update the two fields with the new input for display.  I have a second display just to see whats going on and this display does update the two fields correctly.

There are no differences between these displays (declarations, parameters or values) **HOWEVER**, and here's the lead-up to the **odd** thing, I got a warning when setting the display for the two fields (for displaying in the second sub-menu) and used a suggestion from the pop-up.

The suggestion was to make the TextView static.  I clicked it for one (left the other as-is for trial and commented it).  The warning went away but, **crash!** at run time.

So, here's the **odd** thing:  Nowhere do I see anything that makes this TextView static!  All related declarations and ref's to it are identical to the one I didn't make static.  In fact, I tried to manually make the second one static but couldn't.  I also checked the R.java file but nothing related in there...

Fortunately, I was able to use 'Undo' the Make-it-static.

Any comment/clarification for my education?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Make it Static" suggestion only applies to your Java code.  If you check out the declaration of your `TextView` it will now say something like `static TextView mTextView`.  As for the other problem, there is no way to say for sure what is going on without seeing your code.

Comment: No, I guess I wasn't clear - there is no 'static' in the TextView declaration - the declaration/initializations for both are identical - it's as if there's a hidden tag...

Comment: You're probably looking at the wrong version of your code. Save and refresh

Comment: Oh, forgot, there are 1,000 lines of code and I'm pretty sure I can figure out how to do what's needed for fixing the display (hope I didn't just jinx myself) - my question is really more of curiosity re the odd thing.

Comment: FALMARRI - thanks.  I've been burned too many times by that one! And, pretty do a save/clean upon every change...

Actully, I fixed the display update thing...  thanks, everyone.

Comment: Though I'm making progress on the 'why' it isn't displaying (it's being over written - I'll fix it), I'm still bugged by the Static thing.  Here's the two declarations:
 latOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView10);
 longOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView11);
As, you can see, there is not "static" in the signature.  It's the latOut that has static associated with it (from clicking suggestion).  I searched the entire project for static, none appear in association with latOut.  I'm puzzled.  And, the longOut, is waiting for me to accept the static suggestion... go figure!

Comment: FYI - Even though I cleaned the project and refreshed it, static did not show up until I exited Eclipse IDE and restarted it.  Now, it shows up in a separate declaration for TextView...  and IDE bug...